# NSData with an error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, uiimage, nsdata

Trying to display the image downloaded from web service to `UIImage`, could get the exact image path( by `URLString`) and is displayed in `NSLog`. Now the problem is `imageData` is returning `null` value instead of the value to be returned.

**The error message is to be printed as :**

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)

code used for retrieving the image path are described below,

```
    NSString *urlString = [result objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"url image is %@ \n",urlString);

    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];

    NSError* error = nil; 
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    if (error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"image data is %@ \n",imageData);   
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
```

What is to be done, for displaying the image in the `UIImage`.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` is not suitable for remote image loading - it's a blocking operation, and as you're finding out you get very little error handling and information. You should look into using `NSURLRequest`, or alternatively one of many open-source `UIImage` categories that enable remote image loading directly from the image view.

Comment: Use  AsyncImageView  which is best way to load image url

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
if (error) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

else
NSLog(@"image data is %@ \n",imageData);   
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

it should be:

```
if (error) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

else
{
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

also you are allocating NSData then overwrite the value with another one do not use this line:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
```

it is a waste of time and memory to alloc/init an object then destroy it.

Comment: Frankly, you shouldn't use `dataWithContentsOfURL` for loading remote data over a network anyway.

Comment: it would block the main UI thread but I am not sure he is doing this on the even handler :)

Comment: It's wrong even if you're doing it on a completion handler, because you're calling `UIKit` methods that aren't thread-safe. `dataWithContentsOfURL` was never designed for remote URL loading. It's much, much better to use something like `UIImageView+AFNetworking`, which will handle everything for you *and* give you lots of error handling. One big problem with the NSData method is it has zero feedback in case of network/download failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AsyncImageView to load image

```
 AsyncImageView *ImageView = [AsyncImageView alloc]init];
    ImageView.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURLStr];
```

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView